# error in android:text

Tags: android, android-layout

i am writing a piece of code where it creates a button and put a text on it. here is the piece of code

```
<Button android:id="@+id/start_client"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Start Client" />
```

but the part "android:text="Start Client" />" is being highlighted (yellow), not allowing me to build the project.

Can anybody help me out??

Thanks

Comment: Does putting a space and removing it, re-saving the file solve the problem? Could well be that Eclipse didn't notice your latest changes.

Comment: You should use strings.xml and android:text="@string/YOUR_BUTTON_LABEL"

Comment: The yellow part is `lint` warning you to not use a hard coded string for text(use a string resource from `values/strings.xml`). That is just a warning and it will not block your build, something else in your app it's responsible for that.

Answer (score 0):

//that yellow line is indicating as warning

you need to use res/string file to store text values.

```
[I18N] Hardcoded string "Start Client", should use @string resource
```

this is because of Lint tool.

your project has some other error.

open your problems tab and check whats wrong there.

//clean and build again will also work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The yellow part is a warning to you to not use a hard coded string for text. means you cant give just any string directly to any content like button.

whatever string you want to use, first you will add that in string.xml (check in "values" folder in left side).

after adding any string, you can use in you project anywhere without getting any warning.